# MYSQL Boolean search using table data in same statement

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, boolean-search

I am looking for the most efficient way to do the following.

I have "table1" with the following columns,
ID
SavedSearch
Price
NewLowerPrice

what i need to do is select id and price from table 1, and flag new lower price if the boolean search against another table has  a new lower min price for every saved search by the user.  here is some code I am using, but i am stuck as to how to use table1's saved search in the following boolean search

```
drop temporary table if exists tmp;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp(
ID INT,
Param2 Varchar(300),
LowestPrice decimal(10,2),
LowerPrice bit,
PRIMARY KEY(ID)) ENGINE=MEMORY;

INSERT INTO tmp
SELECT id, Param2, LowestPrice, 0
FROM saved_searches
where user = 28;


UPDATE tmp
set LowerPrice = 1
WHERE (
SELECT MIN(price)
FROM store_sales 
WHERE MATCH (description) AGAINST (concat('\'', tmp.Param2, '\'') IN BOOLEAN MODE)) > 0;
```

it errors out in the update saying "incorrect arguments to AGAINST."
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logically, you're doing something that should make sense, but unfortunately, MySQL's AGAINST() function doesn't allow you to reference a column in your search string. The argument must be a fixed string, [or else a query parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13682355/pdo-and-mysql-fulltext-searches).

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html says:

> The search string must be a string value that is constant during query evaluation. This rules out, for example, a table column because that can differ for each row.

You'll have to do this the hard way:

1. Query for all distinct search params:

   ```
   SELECT DISTINCT Param2 FROM saved_searches;
   ```
2. For each Param2 value, query the min price:

   ```
   SELECT MIN(price)
   FROM store_sales 
   WHERE MATCH (description) AGAINST (:param2) IN BOOLEAN MODE)) > 0;
   ```
3. Update your tmp table when that min price is lower than the currently recorded lowest price for the respective param2 search term.

   ```
   UPDATE tmp
   set LowerPrice = 1
   WHERE LowestPrice > :minPrice Param2 = :param2
   ```

I'm using named parameters in the above examples, the manner you would do with PHP's PDO. But in the stored procedure language, you can use only positional parameters with the `?` placeholder.

It can be tricky to code stored procedures that loop over the results of a query and run inner queries inside the loop. Here's a good blog that shows how to do this: [Nesting MySQL Cursor Loops by Roland Bouman](http://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2005/10/nesting-mysql-cursor-loops.html).