# How to write sql fulltext search with PDO from Mysqli

Tags: php, pdo

I previously used mysqli match..agaist for my fulltext search and it works. Now I would like to convert to PDO but it tells me syntax error with sql. How to fix it? Please notice the `*` next to `:srch_term`

Here is mysqli query:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM memberpost WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST('".$srch_term."*' IN BOOLEAN MODE ) LIMIT 0,15";
```

Here is my PDO:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM memberpost WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST(':srch_term'* IN BOOLEAN MODE ) LIMIT 0,15";
$raw_result = $conn->prepare($sql);
$raw_result->bindParam(':srch_term', $srch_term);
$raw_result->execute();
...
```

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13682355/pdo-and-mysql-fulltext-searches#answer-13682516

Comment: i tried that before I posted this question. The solution there was without * in the sql query of PDO. and I did not work for my case