# MySQL full text search on JSON data

Tags: mysql, json, full-text-search

I'm trying to replicate the following *LIKE* query using a full text search on `JSON` data;

```
SELECT * FROM table
  WHERE response LIKE '%"prod_id": "foo"%'
  AND response LIKE '%"start_date": "2016-07-13"%'
```

In my database the above query returns 28 rows

This is my attempt:

```
SELECT * FROM table
  WHERE MATCH(response)
    AGAINST('+"\"prod_id\": \"foo\"",+"\"start_date\": \"2016-07-13\""')
```

However this returns over 4,500 rows (the same as running the first query for only the **prod_id** ~1,900 rows when running the first query on just the date)

It was my understanding that `+"text here"` would indicate a *required* word, and that literal double quotes (present in the `JSON` data) should be escaped, and that `,` would indicate a split between the two strings I'm looking for. What am I not understanding correctly? Is there any point in running this as a full text query anyway?

Comment: I think that you forgot to add the [IN BOOLEAN MODE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html) modifier to activate those boolean operators. The default modifier is [IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-natural-language.html) which doesn't suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks @Sevle that was certainly half the problem - the rest of my required tweaks are below.

Comment: This is not 5.7 JSON column! It's just a TEXT column where JSON stored as plain text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Sevle I've tweaked my query like so, and it's returning the correct results;

```
SELECT * FROM table
  WHERE MATCH(response)
    AGAINST('+\"prod_id: foo\" +\"start_date: 2016-07-13\"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

The comma was not helping and I was escaping the wrong characters, and of course I did need `IN BOOLEAN MODE` to be added. Finally, I removed the double quotes I was searching for in the `JSON` string.

It may also be worth noting that as I'm using `PHP PDO` to run this query I also had to make the following tweaks.

Instead of constructing the query like so trying to bind the variables like I normally would;

```
$query = $db->prepare('...AGAINST('+\"prod_id: :prod_id\" +\"start_date: :start_date\"');
$query->execute(array('prod_id' => 'foo', 'start_date' => '2016-07-13'));
```

I had to do this, as I found [I could not bind variables in full text searches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13682516/871150)

```
$sql_against = $db->quote('...AGAINST('+\"prod_id: foo\" +\"start_date: 2016-07-13\"');
$query = $db->prepare("...AGAINST($sql_against IN BOOLEAN MODE)")
```